# how to build gnome shell from source?

Tags: linux, build, gnome, meson-build, gnome-shell

I want to install gnome shell on my machine from the [project's gitlab repository](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell) for testing.

I searched their [wiki](https://wiki.gnome.org/) but couldn't find any specific documentation to do this.
I tried with gnome builder but it doesn't work either.

So, how does gnome team test gnome shell and how can i install it on my machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to install the development version directly from GitLab, get the source on your local machine:

```
git clone https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell.git
```

The following solution is from https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/cvs/gnome/gnome-shell.html

Now run:

```
mkdir build &&
cd build &&

meson --prefix=/usr -Dsystemd=false .. &&
ninja
sudo ninja install
```